# How to create noodle (rope/string) like physics in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm trying to create collidable noodle which get pushed by other objects in my game.

I tried to create rigged/skinned mesh in Blender then connect the bones with joints in Unity and tried all of the joints with various settings, but it jitters when bit more than minimum force applied to these bones. Then i tried to bind these bones with script to keep fixed distance from connected bones (next or previous bone) which relative to only one bone/side which works well if it's pulled from one end; but i need it to be relative to both sides to act like noodle. The skinned mesh does the job of keeping it whole, so i think i need some way to control these bones/segments. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time, effort and consideration :).

Script for every node to keep the fixed distance:

```
    void Update() {
      // To keep initial distance
      Vector3 vec = connectedNode.position - transform.position;
      if (vec.magnitude > initialDistance)
         transform.position += 
         (vec.magnitude - initialDistance) * vec.normalized;
    }
```

Comment: HingeJoints, SpringJoints, FixedJoints didn't work for you?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yeah, joints didn't work; works stable when not collided with another objects, for instance It works when connected to kinematic object up in air, but when it collides with ground/floor it jitters.

Comment: Try changing your collision detection method from "Discrete" to one of the Continuous versions.  Also, play with your Physics Fixed Timestep settings.